# Method in parent class that returns child class in java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a parent class `Product` and some children class like `Camera`, `TV`, etc...
Now I want to create a method in `Product` that fetches from db common attributes to all children and returns an instance of a child, according to the object fetched from the db (I have a lot of children class).
Is it possible to do this? If yes, can you show me a little example?

My idea is to call this method from a similar method in child class and then fetching from db all those non-common attributes.

Comment: Cant `Facade` design pattern alleviate your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have a look at decorator pattern

http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/decorator-design-pattern-java-example.html

Answer (score 1):

First, it seems like you'd want to put the db access code into your classes, which I wouldn't recommend.

As for your real problem: try and use an ORM framework such as EclipseLink or Hibernate. Those use a discriminator column to determine the actual class of an entity and create and populate the instance for you. As an alternative (if you can decide on the database) you could also have a look at [ObjectDB](http://www.objectdb.com/).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Product{
    int productId;

    protected Product(int productId){ //avoid creating pure product objects
        this.productId = productId;
        //load all the common properties            
    }

    public Product getProduct(int productId){
        // read the product with productId from the table
        // identify the type of the product
        String type = .... (assume its "camera")
        if("camera".equals(type)){
            return new Camera(productId);
        } 
    }
}
```

in the child class,

```
public class Camera extends Product{
    public Camera(int productId){
        super(productId);
    }
}
```

usage

```
Product p = Product.getProduct(4025);
```

the method will load the relevant field from the database, identify the type of the product, create a subclass object based on the type of the product and call its constructor.

the constructor of the child class calls the super class constructor.
the super class constructor loads all the common properties.